# Ведение базы данных учета командировок и больничных листов

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 CREATE TABLE Worker
(
        ТабельныйНомер INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
        Имя NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        Фамилия NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Отчетсво NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ГодРождения INT NOT NULL CHECK(ГодРождения >= 1900 AND ГодРождения <= 2002),
    ДатаПринятия Date NOT NULL,
    Должность NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL REFERENCES Position(Должность), 
);

CREATE TABLE SickLeave
(
        НомерБольничногоЛиста INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    ТабельныйНомер INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Worker(ТабельныйНомер),
    ДатаНачала Date NOT NULL,
    ДатаОкончания Date NOT NULL,
    constraint CK_ДатаОкончания CHECK (ДатаОкончания >= ДатаНачала)
);

CREATE TABLE Position
(
        Должность NVARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Оклад INT CHECK(Оклад >= 0) NOT NULL,
    Подразделение NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

- справочник подразделений и их работников;
- количество людей, которые имели командировки по каждому подразделению;
- количество людей, которые болели и имеют больничные листы в текущем месяце, продолжительность больничного;
- общий список людей, которые не имеют больничные листы (по алфавиту).
- создать таблицу работников возраст которых более 60 лет

Comment: *Но почему-то в SickLeave ругается на дату окончания, как сделать проверку чтоб дата начала не была позднее даты начала?* CHECK CONSTRAINT поля может использовать только значение проверяемого поля и константы. Если выполняется сравнение со значением другого поля - это должен быть табличный CONSTRAINT, который записывается отдельной кляузой.

Comment: ДатаНачала Date NOT NULL,
ДатаОкончания Date NOT NULL,
constraint CK_ДатаОкончания CHECK (ДатаОкончания >= ДатаНачала)

Comment: Корректируйте текст вопроса (ссылка "править" под ним), не используйте комментарии для фактов. Можете пометить дополнение (текстом UPDATE или горизонтальной линией).

Comment: В чем вопрос - непонятно.

Comment: @Kromster Закрытия вполне достаточно. Минусовсть не стоит, так как это демотивирует. Участник хоть и не совсем разобрался, как задавть вопросы, но проявил старание по оформлению вопроса.

Comment: @0xdb участник проявил старание по форматированию копипасты своего ТЗ и даже не задал вопроса .. это вполне соответствует хинту у стрелки вниз.

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139183

Answer (score 0):

`ДатаОкончания` всегда должна быть больше `ДатаНачала`, нету смысла в событии, которое нисколько не продлилось. Вот тут надо заменить:

```
constraint CK_ДатаОкончания CHECK (ДатаОкончания > ДатаНачала)
```